# Get Actual CSS Property of element if it dynamically added "!important"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Element with the id="somID";

For Example:

Html:

`<div id='somID' ></div>`

Css :

`#somID{ width:500px;height:500px}`

and i have a class named : maximize.

So,

`.maximize{width:100% !important; height:100% !important; }`

Now dynamically i added the class `.maximize` to my div `#somID`

And after that i wanna get the width and height of my `#somID` by calling with its ID like,

`$('#somID').width() or .height()`

but i want to take the actual height of element that is defined in its ID but i get the `.maximize` in result not the height or width that is in `#somID`.

Any buddy have any idea ? That how to retrieve the height of div#somID if it contains `.maximize` ??

Comment: You can do it but it's slightly messy. Remove class `maximize` from the element, make your measurement, then reapply `maximize`.

Comment: If i do so,then my screen gets blink's for a while ..is there not an another option ??

Comment: Your only other option is to measure the element before `maximise` is first applied and remember the measurement either as a javascript var or as an attribute of the element itself.

Comment: ohk.. thats the trick..Thanks for that @Beetroot-Beetroot :)

Comment: Why do you want to add a class to maximise something? I think you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: As I was created my all code i just want the solution for that,and not want to modify something on my written code! so is there any thing to get original dimensions ? @MMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, there can be many, many selectors that are applied to a given element, with different specificities. There is no API that allows you to request a property from a selector in CSS - it simply wouldn't make much sense.

Having said that, you can create a hack to solve that issue:

```
function getOriginalDimensions(id) {
     var $a = $("<div>", {id:id});
     $("body").append($a);
     var width = $a.width();
     var height = $a.height();
     $a.remove();
     return {width:width, height:height};
}

console.log(getOriginalDimensions("somID")); // returns {width:500, height:500}
```

The above works with your example HTML and CSS.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g86vd/)

This basically creates an element with the same ID, appends it to the body, reads the dimensions and deletes it immediately. This is necessary because the div will have no size if it is just kept as a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and not added to the DOM, because the CSS will not get applied.

In theory you could expand this function to make it work with other selectors.

However bear in mind this is a **nasty hack** and you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: This will works but it return only correct height and when i call it for width it return just my screen width not that one i define in somID.

Comment: No, it returns the width you've defined in `somID`, at least according to my tests in Chrome.

Comment: k.. so will you please provide me your fiddle link ?

Comment: Great Working... Working on both IE as well as Chrome !! Thanks @MMM

Comment: Please note; whereas this answer works for the OP, it is not a universal solution. I considered this approach and immediately dismissed it as it will only work in limited circumstances. In order to be a reliable measure of the original element, a temporary element with the same id would need to emulate the original in every regard that might affect its dimensions. Factors include (a) other CSS directives (not just `#somID{...}`), (b) the element's content and (c) its position within the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

A. Make your measurements and save them as `.data` attributes of the element :

```
var $el = $('#somID');
$el.data('original_dims', {
    height: $el.height(),
    width: $el.width()
}
```

B. Add class that changes the dimensions of the element :

```
    $el.addClass('maximise');
```

C. Retrive the original dimensions whenever they are needed

```
var h = $el.data('original_dims').height;
var w = $el.data('original_dims').width;
```